# How to pull out variable-length lists using PyParsing

Tags: pyparsing

I have the following data:

```
protocol:: DHCP Other items
following:: line
```

I'd like to pull the "protocol" data strings into an array of ['dhcp', 'other', 'items'], and then have the following line parsed as a separate thing.  I've tried `'protocol::' + OneOrMore(Word(alphas))`, but that is eating up the following lines as well.

I've tried a several different variations of this, and nothing has worked.  Is there a preferred way of doing this?

eg:

```
text = """
protocol:: DHCP some other thing
following:: line
"""

delim = '::'
proto_line = Group('protocol' + delim + OneOrMore(Word(alphanums)))
following_line = Group('following' + delim + OneOrMore(Word(alphanums)))
grammar = OneOrMore(proto_line | following_line)
print grammar.parseString(text).dump()
```

prints:

```
[['DHCP', 'some', 'other', 'thing', 'following']]
[0]:
  ['DHCP', 'some', 'other', 'thing', 'following']
```

and I would like `[[protocol stuff], [following stuff]]`.

Comment: What indicates the end of the value? The end of the line? The start of another value? Have you looked at the new `stopOn` feature for `OneOrMore`?

Comment: Hello Paul, I have not!  Thank you, I'll give that a shot.  Regards and thanks for your continued community support.